# What is the static shared libraries feature introduced in API level 26?

Tags: android, android-source

Seems Google quietly introduced some kind of shared library functionality in Android API level 26:

https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/26/changes

Notice the following new class among other things:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/SharedLibraryInfo

Apparently the Android manifest can include the tag `static-library`.

Perhaps this is related to Android's rarely used `library` feature which allows system builders to link against these exposed built-in libraries available to developers via `uses-library` in the manifest.

Comment: Is this going to be used in Project Mainline: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/05/whats-new-in-android-q-beta-3-more.html